# How can I merge rows by multiple columns, taking the last non-null value in multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, aggregate

I'm learning how to do aggregation operations using R, but there is a particular type of operation I use frequently that I'm hoping has a built in operation in R or one of its add-ons, or at least that there's a better implementation than what I've come up with. I'm not sure if there's a technical term for this, but I call it a MUSH operation. It's where you essentially mash a dirty dataset with a bunch of missing data in random places into one clean dataset. Sometimes I need the first non-null value, sometimes the last, sometimes the last value regardless of whether it's null or not. For the sake of simplicity, here's an example where I'm only worried about the last non-null value.

Let's say I have a list of students with their test scores, subject, and the teacher who administered the test. The data entry person is a bit careless (purely hypothetical) and has left some teacher names off. In addition, there's a few students who were absent when the test was initially administered and had to take the test at a later date.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
   STUDENTID SUBJECT TEACHER SCORE
1:       100     Art    <NA>    96
2:       100     Art   Smith    NA
3:       100 Science   Jones    75
4:       101     Art   Smith    NA
5:       101     Art   Smith    50
6:       101 Science   Jones    75
7:       102     Art    <NA>    80
8:       102     Art   Smith    NA
```

Here's the code to setup the data frame:

```
# Setup data
a<-data.table(cbind(
  "STUDENTID"=c("100","100","101","102")
  ,"SUBJECT"=c("Art","Science","Art","Art"))
  ,"TEACHER"=c("Smith","Jones","Smith","Smith")
  ,"SCORE"=c(NA,75,50,NA)
)
b<-data.table(
  "STUDENTID"=c("100","101","101","102")
  ,"SUBJECT"=c("Art","Art","Science","Art")
  ,"TEACHER"=c(NA,"Smith","Jones",NA)
  ,"SCORE"=c(96,NA,75,80)
)
# Merge data
d <- merge(a, b, by = NULL, all = TRUE)
# Show output
d
```

I want to clean up this dataset by merging all the rows based on STUDENTID and SUBJECT. I want to take the first non-null value for each of the other rows. The resulting output should look like this:

```
   STUDENTID SUBJECT TEACHER SCORE
1:       100     Art   Smith    96
2:       100 Science   Jones    75
3:       101     Art   Smith    50
4:       101 Science   Jones    75
5:       102     Art   Smith    80
```

The following code accomplishes this task:

```
# dplyr to get last non null values
library(dplyr)
d <- d %>%
  group_by(STUDENTID, SUBJECT) %>% 
  mutate(
    bestTeacherRow = dplyr::last(na.omit(TEACHER)),
    bestScoreRow = dplyr::last(na.omit(SCORE))
  )
# Replace values with non-nulls
d$TEACHER <- d$bestTeacherRow
d$SCORE <- d$bestScoreRow
# Remove duplicates
d <- unique(d)
#Show output
d
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? It doesn't matter if it uses dplyr or another add-on.

More importantly, is there a way to do this without specifying each header/variable name? For example, if at some point in the future the DATE the test was administered is added to the dataset, I could run the same code and get the same result. I'm often having to add or remove variables from my datasets and having to go back and manually change them throughout the process of transforming the data gets unmanageable really fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do an `order` on the `NA` elements by group and remove the `NA` rows with `na.omit`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(d[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]), .(STUDENTID, SUBJECT)])
```

-output

```
    STUDENTID SUBJECT TEACHER SCORE
1:       100     Art   Smith    96
2:       100 Science   Jones    75
3:       101     Art   Smith    50
4:       101 Science   Jones    75
5:       102     Art   Smith    80
```

Comment: Wow, simple and elegant. Great answer. Also, r is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Another `data.table` option that simply finds the first non-`NA` (if present):

```r
d[, lapply(.SD, function(z) z[!is.na(z)][1]), by = .(STUDENTID, SUBJECT)]
#    STUDENTID SUBJECT TEACHER SCORE
#       <char>  <char>  <char> <num>
# 1:       100     Art   Smith    96
# 2:       100 Science   Jones    75
# 3:       101     Art   Smith    50
# 4:       101 Science   Jones    75
# 5:       102     Art   Smith    80
```

Comment: Thanks! This would have probably been my next question, but you've already answered it.